# How to extract the year and quarter from reporting date variable?

Tags: string, date, stata

I have this reporting date variable (report_date). How can I use stata code to create two new variable columns with the year and quarters extracted from the reporting date?
Any advice appreciated. Thanks.

[Stata browser screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1r5I.png)

Comment: No research effort evident. Images are helpful, but showing data directly using code is much more helpful. See the Stata tag wiki here and `help dataex` in Stata (if need be `search dataex`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic stuff: You should be using `search` or `help` to find `help datetime`.

Let's focus on `"12/31/82"` as a string date. The following statements show date functions in use. Here the command `di` is in full `display` and as an exercise you need the corresponding actions using the commands `generate` to generate variables and `format` to apply an appropriate date display format.

```
. di daily("12/31/82", "MDY", 2020)
8400

. di %td daily("12/31/82", "MDY", 2020)
31dec1982

. di year(daily("12/31/82", "MDY", 2020))
1982

. di quarter(daily("12/31/82", "MDY", 2020))
4

. di %tq qofd(daily("12/31/82", "MDY", 2020))
1982q4
```

Comment: Thank you. I have trouble understanding the Stata manual sometimes.